# Getting grub message after deleting Ubuntu partition and unable to boot into Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, boot-repair, windows-10

I deleted my Ubuntu partition because I wanted to install Linux Mint. But now when I switch on my laptop, I'm unable to boot into Windows. I'm getting a grub terminal (not sure if it's grub rescue mode) on startup.

It says:

```
Gnu grub version 2.02^beta2-9ubuntu1.3
Minimal bash like line editing is supported 
For the first word, tab lists possible command completions. Anywhere else tab lists possible device or file completions .
grub>
```

Comment: Go to this link to get windows boot loader back. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using the Windows cd?

Comment: Close voters: Using grub is part of Ubuntu too. It's even an Ubuntu version of grub!

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB and then 
open up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> and type in

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You shoud get someing like this

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000200658432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121600 cylinders, total 1953516911 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000255a1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   922578943   461186048    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       922580992  1953513471   515466240    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

my disk is /dev/sda yours might be different. 
now type in

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

**change /dev/sda to your drive**

Then run

```
sudo update-grub /dev/sda
```

the you should see something like this.

```
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

Reboot your computer and you should be able to boot into windows

Hope it Helps.